# Mypy: Using unions in mapping types does not work as expected

Tags: python, mypy

Consider the following code:

```
def foo(a: dict[str | tuple[str, str], str]) -> None:
    pass


def bar(b: dict[str, str]) -> None:
    foo(b)


def baz(b: dict[tuple[str, str], str]) -> None:
    foo(b)


foo({"foo": "bar"})
foo({("foo", "bar"): "bar"})
```

When checked with mypy in strict mode it produces the following errors:

```
file.py:6: error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "Dict[str, str]"; expected "Dict[Union[str, Tuple[str, str]], str]"
file.py:9: error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "Dict[Tuple[str, str], str]"; expected "Dict[Union[str, Tuple[str, str]], str]"
```

Which doesn't seem to make sense to me. The parameter is defined to accept a `dict` with either a string or a tuple as keys and strings as values. However, both variants are not accepted when explicitly annotated as such. They do however work when passing a dict like this directly to the function. It seems to me that mypy expects a dict that **has** to be able to have both options of the union as keys. I fail to understand why? If the constraints for the key are to be either a string or a tuple of to strings, passing either should be fine. Right? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `dict[str | tuple[str, str], str]` isn't just a dict with either `str` or `tuple[str, str]` keys. It's a dict you can *add more* `str` or `tuple[str, str]` keys to.

You can't add `str` keys to a `dict[tuple[str, str], str]`, and you can't add `tuple[str, str]` keys to a `dict[str, str]`, so those types aren't compatible.

If you pass a literal dict directly to `foo` (or to `bar` or `baz`), that literal has no static type. mypy infers a type for the dict based on the context. Many different types may be inferred for a literal based on its context. When you pass `b` to `foo` inside `bar` or `baz`, `b` already has a static type, and that type is incompatible with `foo`'s signature.

Comment: So, just to be clear, the issue is that - to mypy - dictionaries are invariant? I previously tried to find information on this before but couldn't come up with anything, and since mypy wasn't telling me that this is because dicts are invariant I assumed that they're not.

Comment: But if I use `Mapping` (not mutable) i have the same error. `Mypy: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "Mapping[str, str]"; expected "Mapping[Union[str, Tuple[str, 
 str]], str]"`

Answer (score 1):

So, I was finally able to figure out what the issue is. As I suspected after [@user2357112 supports Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica)'s answer, `Mapping` is in fact [invariant on the key](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/445). There is no good reason for this other than it apparently being hard to implement because of how `Mapping` itself is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

What would work here is

```py
def foo(a: dict[str, str] | dict[tuple[str, str], str]) -> None:
    pass
```

Or you would have to help mypy and explicitly type annotate the dicts you are passing like

```py
mydict : dict[str | tuple[str, str], str] = {"a" : "b"}
foo(mydict) # your foo as typed in your example
```